# Python - HTTP Proxy over files in network share

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, proxy, server

My situation is the following:

I have two PCs that are on a local network but with a firewall in between so that they don't see each other or can be accessed in any way.
The only way to exchange data is through a shared network drive that they both see. There is no other way to communicate between the PCs and I have no access to the firewall to change anything there.

On one PC I have a browser running from which I want to access a HTTP Server on the other PC.

So what I want to exchange through that network share is HTTP traffic - in other words - a proxy that works not through internet but through files.

Is there any library or project for that? I am sure I'm not the first one with this scenario.

My idea is to run a local server on the browser side that is accessed instead of the actual server. This one writes the HTTP request to a file. On the other PC I poll the network share for an incoming request file, read the request and forward it to the actual destination server. The response from the server goes back the same way over a separate file.

Comment: I'm in the process of writing it but it's not finished yet. Essentially I have a python program with two threads on each side of the network share: One thread to handle incoming traffic and translate to files and one for monitoring files an translating them to http requests and responses.